# SignInResult.RequiresTwoFactor always return false

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-identity, identity, asp.net-core-2.2, .net-core-2.2

In my dotnet core 2.2 application I am trying to enable two factor authentication. In the startup class I have created a seed data function that will generate a sample user. I use UserManager to create the user and then set the two factor required flag. But when the user signs in it always succeeds and never reaches the RequireTwoFactor flag if statement.

I'm pretty sure that I am missing something in my startup class.

All help is appreciated.

startup class Configure method

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
{
    options.Tokens.AuthenticatorTokenProvider = "email";
});
```

seed data method

```
var User = new IdentityUser() { UserName = email, Email = email };
await UserManager.CreateAsync(User, password);
await UserManager.SetTwoFactorEnabledAsync(User, true);
```

sign in page

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
    }
    if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
    {
        return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
    }
    if (result.IsLockedOut)
    {
        _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
        return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
        return Page();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have had the same problem.

Today I updated to .net core `3.0.100-rc1-014190` and the problem is resolved. So if the 'TwoFactorEnabled' flag is set in the ASPNetUsers table PasswordSignInAsync will return the result with RequiresTwoFactor

Answer (score 5):

We had the same problem.
Before changing the netcore's version, my  team noticed that user's email hasn't been validated yet.
They validated the email and the problem was solved.

Comment: Yep, I had to set `EmailConfirmed = true` in addtion to `TwoFactorEnabled = true` for the particular user in db to reach `RequiresTwoFactor` sign-in result. It seems that `PhoneNumberConfirmed` value doesn't affect the sign-in result at all at my current setup (dotnet core 3.1)

Comment: Is CheckPasswordSignInAsync still working OK under .NET5? In my case CheckPasswordSignInAsync always return Succeeded even when EmailConfirmed and TwoFactorEnabled both are set to true for this user. First EmailConfirmed and then TwoFactorEnabled. But, when I logged in with this user credentials the result is Succeeded and not TwoFactorRequired what I expect.

Answer (score 1):

I've just experienced the same issue with .net core 3.1.416, whilst implementing a custom MFA provider.  I wasn't to keen on the "EmailConfirmed = true" solution so looked into it some more.

I found that it is not enough to set TwoFactorEnabled to true you must also create an entry in the ASPNetUserTokens table.

This can be achieved with the following

```
await _userManager.ResetAuthenticatorKeyAsync(user);
await _userManager.GetAuthenticatorKeyAsync(user);
await _userManager.SetTwoFactorEnabledAsync(user, true);
```